# How to make the page to scroll to the left when elements placed in a negative position?

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar, positioning, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to create an application similar to a mind map but it doesn't have to be as complicated. The problem that I have is that when I place an element on the page and make it draggable with jQuery draggable function, the element can be dragged to the right and the page's width increases as you drag the element but when you drag the element to the left which gets a negative value, the scrollbar doesn't cover the negative space.

I have searched everywhere and couldn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

JavaScript Code

```
$( function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable();
});
```

HTML markup:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <div id="draggable">
  Can be dragged to the right of the screen and the scrollbar increases but 
  not to the left.
  </div>
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/r1sqcqap/)

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar isn't supposed to extend towards the top or left sides of the page, but you could work around this with javascript by increasing the page size if the draggable is dropped onto negative coordinates and resetting its position, for example

```js
var increasedLeft = 0;

$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.position.left < 0) {
        $("#draggable").css({left: 0});
        $("#container").width($("#container").width() - ui.position.left);
        increasedLeft -= ui.position.left;
      } else if (increasedLeft > 0) {
       $("#container").width($("#container").width() - Math.min(increasedLeft, ui.position.left));
        $("#draggable").css({left: (ui.position.left - Math.min(increasedLeft, ui.position.left))});
       increasedLeft -= Math.min(increasedLeft, ui.position.left);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#draggable {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="draggable">
      Can be dragged to the right of the screen and the scrollbar increases but not to the left.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, this should do it for now.

Comment: @HamidHosseini No problem! If my answer solved your problem you can accept it as the correct answer through clicking on the check mark left from the answer.